# How to compress an image in Android 13 APIs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-13

I have made image compression long ago. It was working well until [Android X](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx), but above Android it’s not working.

```
public class ImageCompress {

    private static final int IMAGE_QUALITY = 99;
    private static final int MAX_SIZE_PIXELS = 1200;

    public static Bitmap decodeFile(File file, int width, int height) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = width;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = height;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                    && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options newOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            newOptions.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, newOptions);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static File compressImage(final File file, String outputDirectory, Context context) {
        String path = file.getPath();
        String format = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".")).substring(1);
        Bitmap source;
        try {
            source = decodeFile(file, MAX_SIZE_PIXELS, MAX_SIZE_PIXELS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(ImageCompress.class.toString(), e.toString() + " Something happened wrong");
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat;

        // If PNG or WebP have the allowed resolution, then do not compress it
        if ("png".equals(format) || "webp".equals(format)) return file;

        // Select format
        switch (format) {
            case "png":
                compressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
                break;
            case "webp":
                compressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP;
                break;
            case "gif":
                return file;
            default:
                compressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
        }

        // Resize image
        Bitmap resizedBmp;
    // I am getting an error on the source.getHeight() line
        if (source.getHeight() > MAX_SIZE_PIXELS || source.getWidth() > MAX_SIZE_PIXELS) {
            resizedBmp = resizeBitmap(source, MAX_SIZE_PIXELS);
        } else {
            resizedBmp = source;
        }
        File result = null;
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            ContentResolver resolver = BaseApplication.getInstance().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, file.getName());
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/" + format);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Constants.MULTIMEDIA_CHATROOM_11);
            Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            try {
                fOut = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
                result = new File(Utils.getPath(BaseApplication.getInstance(), imageUri));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // create directory if not exist
            File directory = new File(outputDirectory);
            int code = context.getPackageManager().checkPermission(
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    context.getPackageName());
            if (code == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(ImageCompress.class.getSimpleName(), "creating directory");
                if (!directory.isDirectory() || !directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(ImageCompress.class.getSimpleName(), "failed access");
            }

            // Compress image
            result = new File(outputDirectory, file.getName());

            try {
                if (!result.exists()) {
                    result.createNewFile();
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(result);
                } else {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(result);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            resizedBmp.compress(compressFormat, IMAGE_QUALITY, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            source.recycle();
            resizedBmp.recycle();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        // Copy EXIF orientation from the original image
        try {
            ExifInterface oldExif = new ExifInterface(file.getPath());
            String exifOrientation = oldExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
            if (exifOrientation != null) {
                ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(result.getPath());
                newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, exifOrientation);
                newExif.saveAttributes();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap source, int maxSizePixels) {
        int targetWidth, targetHeight;
        double aspectRatio;

        if (source.getWidth() > source.getHeight()) {
            targetWidth = maxSizePixels;
            aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
            targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
        } else {
            targetHeight = maxSizePixels;
            aspectRatio = (double) source.getWidth() / (double) source.getHeight();
            targetWidth = (int) (targetHeight * aspectRatio);
        }

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
    }
}
```

My app is made for social entertainment purposes, so I don't have storage access like before due to policies. So we can use only the session scope way to access files. I am getting an error at line source.getHeight() and source.getWidth() as both are zero. How can I fix this this issue for all Android versions?

Error:

[image: Getting error]

Please note: I noticed this error comes in a few pictures from the gallery.

Comment: Please describe in detail what "not working" means. What errors does it cause?

Comment: Hi, robert I mentioned comment in code already. the comment is "//getting error on source.getHeight() line" basically we can do only media query to fetch image if want to publish app in playstore. the source.getHeight() returning 0.

Comment: What error do you get? Do you simply get 0 as return value or an exception? If you get an exception please include the full output into your question (not in comments!).

Comment: @Robert done sir. and am very glad that you are trying to helping me.

Comment: Please never paste stack traces as image into question. Just copy & paste the text. Fro what I see the most likely error is that you run into the catch block `FileNotFoundException` in `decodeFile`. Thus the return value is null and so `source` becomes `null`. => never catch an Exception and return null if your code can not handle this. So I assume your error is you try to load a non-existant file.

Comment: @Robert Thank you so much sir for writing again. Yes you are correct about  FileNotFoundException I diagnose that permission was denied. so I check what permissions are restricted I found photos and videos permission was denied in my samsung phone. so finally figure out because of you. now I need to know what is minimum api level which need these special permissions (images and videos, music and audio). Also I request you to write in answer so I can mark it as answer sir.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76605043/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a `NullPointerException` on `source.getHeight()` then this means `source` has been set to `null`.

The only point where `source`is set is on the line

```
source = decodeFile(file, MAX_SIZE_PIXELS, MAX_SIZE_PIXELS);
```

This means the method `decodeFile` has to return a null value.

Looking at the method `decodeFile` you can see tha there are only two different code paths that return a value. The first code path returns the value of `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(..)` which AFAIK should never return `null`.

The it is most likely the other code path in the `FileNotFoundException`  catch clause.

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File file, int width, int height) {
    try {
        ....
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, newOptions);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This leads to the conclusion that at some point you are trying to read a File that does not exist or on that you don't have read permissions.

As your app is older the chance is high that if it is a permission problem and the file is on the shared storage (`/sdcard` or subfolder) this is because the app does not make use of scoped storage system introduced with Android 10/11.

Answer (score -2):

```
public File compressImage(File fileimage) {
  Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(fileimage));
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bytes);
  String folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/" + "Images") + "/";
  File directory = new File(folder);
  if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdirs();
  }
  File f = new File(folder + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
  try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return f;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.